# How to start at the top of the page with a bash script

Tags: bash

I am working on a bash script and would like to make it look pretty. I have seen scripts where once run, it starts printing at the top of the terminal window. Instead of writing at the bottom of the window and scrolling up as needed, it automatically scrolls so that the prompt is at the top of the window and write down from there.
Apologies if I am unclear. I am sort of at a loss as to how to describe this better. Let me know if you need further clarification.
Thanks!
jBit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `clear` on top of the script, before any output is generated:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
# actual work
# ...
```